# add a new column of numbers to whitespace delimited data based on another column of numbers using Bash utilities

Tags: bash, text, addition, whitespace, delimited

I want to perform a simple calculation on each number in a column of whitespace delimited data using Bash utilities such as cut and bc. The data may look like something such as the following:

```
string 0.998663 string string string
string 0.998592 string string string
string 0.999096 string string string
```

Let's say I want to change the show the numbers in the second column to three significant figures. I want to add another column of these new numbers to this data directly following the second column. So, the result may look like something such as the following:

```
string 0.998663 0.999 string string string
string 0.998592 0.999 string string string
string 0.999096 0.999 string string string
```

I know that I can manually cycle through all of this data and then construct new columns of data, but I imagine that there is a more efficient way of doing this. Would you happen to know of some clever way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this short line:

```
awk '$2=$2" "sprintf("%.3f",$2)' file
```

with your example data:

```
kent$  echo "string 0.998663 string string string
string 0.998592 string string string
string 0.999096 string string string"|awk '$2=$2" "sprintf("%.3f",$2)'
string 0.998663 0.999 string string string
string 0.998592 0.999 string string string
string 0.999096 0.999 string string string
```

Comment: +1 but I would use `FS` instead of " " i.e. `awk '$2=$2 FS sprintf("%.3f",$2)' file`

Comment: I knew it could be optimized. Nice solution!

Comment: This is efficient and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
awk '{printf("%s %s %.3f %s %s %s\n",$1,$2,$2,$3,$4,$5)}' file
```

**Test**

```
$ awk '{printf("%s %s %.3f %s %s %s\n",$1,$2,$2,$3,$4,$5)}' file
string 0.998663 0.999 string string string
string 0.998592 0.999 string string string
string 0.999096 0.999 string string string
```

Comment: You don't need a loop here! `awk '{printf("%s %s %.3f %s %s %s\n",$1,$2,$2,$3,$4,$5)}' file` is enough.

Comment: i am not sure if it is fast solution.. you started/stopped awk process linenumber times.